# Can I access the elements in a c++ std::map by an integer index?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, openmp, stdmap

I have a map of elements that I would like to iterate through.  Of course, the standard way to do that would be using a for loop with

```
for (map<string, int> iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
    string thisKey = it->first;
    int thisValue = it->second;
}
```

but if I try and make this loop run parallel using OpenMP's *parallel for* construct, it doesn't work, and this is (apparently) a known issue, as it doesn't recognize this sort of loop construct.

So, my backup plan was to use an integer index iterator, and access the list of keys and values by index, as I would do in C# like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myMap.Count; ++i) {
    string thisKey = myMap.Keys[i];
    string thisValue = myMap.Values[i];
}
```

... yet I can't seem to find an equivalent method in C++.  Is there a way to do this in C++ that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Are you sure `std::map` is the best container for what wish to accomplish?

Comment: Iterating through a map is a tree traversal, it isn't a simple operation. Even if you were able to index it the way you want, it wouldn't parallelize for you.

Comment: how many pairs are in this map of yours?

Comment: Mark: Thanks, that pretty much answers my question.  I think my current solution (iterate through the tree and copy the results into vectors, then iterate through the vectors) is probably the best way to go.

JK: for this particular application, 99991.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know anything about [OpenMP](http://OpenMP.org), so I don't know if it will optimize the following or not. But you could use [`std::advance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/), like so:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> Map;

int main() {
  Map m;
  m["one"] = 1;
  m["two"] = 2;
  for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
    Map::iterator it = m.begin();
    std::advance(it, i);
    std::string thiskey = it->first;
    int thisValue = it->second;
    std::cout << thiskey << "\n";
  }
}
```

But do be aware that `std::advance` is O(n), so your (single-threaded) complexity is O(n^2).

---

**EDIT**: If you copy the map elements to a vector, realize you can do that in one declaration:

```
std::vector<Map::value_type> v(m.begin(), m.end());
```

thus:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> Map;

int main() {
  Map m;
  m["one"] = 1;
  m["two"] = 2;
  int i = 0;
  for( std::vector<Map::value_type> v(m.begin(), m.end());
    i < v.size(); ++i) {
    std::string thiskey = v[i].first;
    int thisValue = v[i].second;
    std::cout << thiskey << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that.. it is horribly slow.  I lose almost all the time I gain by running it multi-threaded, and I have 24 threads going.

My present solution right now is to declare a vector<string> and a vector<int>, resize them, and dump the data into the vectors, then access them that way.. it adds very little overhead but it seems like such a kluge.

Comment: It might be better to keep a single vector of `map::value_type`. See my edit.  (Hmmm, but that won't `reserve` enough initial memory.)

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few options that are *relatively* painless.

1. Keep a `std::vector` or `std::deque` for array access, and a separate map of values.  The leg work of ensuring that they are consistent is *your* problem.
2. Use [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to ensure consistency between the two index structures.  As a word of warning, compile times are pretty long with this option.  Consider using [the pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) if you go this route.

I have no experience with OpenMP, so I cannot speculate if either of these options would be worthwhile in practice.